# Audio not playing dynamically When the audio file is in webserver?

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0, mediaelement

When I try to play a Audio file , on http severr from silverlight code behind, unable to do so:

```
string mediaFileName = "http://myserverIP/file.mp3";
musicPlayer.Source = new Uri("mediaFileName", UriKind.Relative);
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(musicPlayer);
musicPlayer.Play();
```

Now this should play the files easily. I dont understand why this is not happening. Insted of the webfile if I am placing the file inside Clientbin, it works pretty well.

Again when I try to play the web file from XAML like below,it works:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaPlayer" Source="http://myserverIP/file.mp3" BindingValidationError="mediaPlayer_BindingValidationError" />
```

Please help.

Thanks,
Subhen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M sorry , Really Sorry , did a Silly Mistake.

```
musicPlayer.Source = new Uri("mediaFileName", UriKind.Relative);
```

Above, I passed `mediaFileName` as string again.

This should be as below:

```
 musicPlayer.Source = new Uri(mediaFileName, UriKind.Relative);
```